# input function putting extra line

Tags: python

Here is a simple code I was playing with

```
input("This is test:")
input("This is test:")
input("This is test:")
```

So, it prompted me to give some input and when I entered input as numbers, I got the following output.

```
This is test:1

This is test:2

This is test:3
```

So, I am wondering where the extra lines coming from. The documentation says that `input` function strips newline character at the end. So, where do extra lines come from ?

Thanks

Comment: I am not getting this behaviour.

Comment: How are you running this code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extra line in output when printing inside a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10456293/extra-line-in-output-when-printing-inside-a-loop)

Comment: I have put the code in file inside Spyder(Python 3.8) Anaconda and checking the output.

Comment: are you using this: `print(input("This is test:"))` Then you must know that print appends a newline, and the input lines already end with a newline.

Comment: @Fareed, no. I am not using any print function here.  I just put the code I showed in .py file and run it inside Anaconda Spyder.  I tried closing and restarting again. Same output again with extra line.

Comment: isn't this caused by your command line? I am not getting this behavior

Comment: Not on command line.  Inside Spyder console. On command line, I get the expected output

Comment: @user9026, this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44667227/how-can-i-prevent-spyder-from-inserting-a-new-line-after-taking-user-input